# Symfony2 load conditional configuration

Tags: symfony

I just started with Symfony2, so I'm still very noob.

I need to load a config file (yml) based on either the request uri, or a specific route.

E.G

```
/{dynamicroute}
```

should load dynamicroute.yml

and

```
/{anotherdynamicroute}
```

should load anotherdynamicroute.yml

(hope it makes sense)

**UPDATE**:

Basically what I want to to is this:

We have one backend system where all our clients can log in.
From there they can set up facebook applications.
I'm using the FOSFacebookBundle so users can connect to facebook.
The FOSFacebookBundle requires the facebook settings to be set in config.yml, but because we will have multiple facebook applications running of the one system, I can't put the facebook settings in the config.yml.

So what I was thinking is to load a client specific configuration based on the route.
For example I will create a route that will look something like this:

```
// src\Acme\MyBundle\Controller\DemoController.php
/**
 * @Route("/client/{client_id}")
 */
public function indexAction($client_id)
{
    // load client specific data
```

so when the user loads the specific client's page, I want to load a yml configuration with the facebook details for that specific client, so the users can register with facebook with te client's facebook details using the FOSFacebookBundle

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676247/symfony2-how-to-extend-a-vendor-bundle-e-g-of-fosfacebookbundle for the same problem (and a solution)