# Symfony2 - how to extend a vendor bundle (e.g. of FOSFacebookBundle)

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosfacebookbundle

**Scenario:**

I'm using a bundle (FOSFacebookBundle) that allows me to set parameters for exactly one facebook app in my configuration. Everything works perfectly fine, but now I need to set not only one app, but multiple.

**My approach:**

I've created a AcmeFacebookBundle, which allows multiple apps to be defined (configuration defined in *Acme\FacebookBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration*) in an array like so:

```
acme_facebook:
    apps:
        some_competition:
            server_url: %acme.facebook.some_competition.server_url%
            file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
            alias:  facebook
            app_id: %acme.facebook.some_competition.app_id%
            secret: % acme .facebook.some_competition.secret%
            cookie: true
            permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]
        some_other_competition:
            server_url: %acme.facebook. some_other_competition.server_url%
            file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
            alias:  facebook
            app_id: %acme.facebook. some_other_competition.app_id%
            secret: % acme .facebook. some_other_competition.secret%
            cookie: true
            permissions: [email, user_birthday, user_location]
```

In *Acme\FacebookBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeFacebookExtension* I am then looping through all apps. The idea is to compare the server_url parameter against the current URL and override the fos_facebook configuration with mine.

```
class AcmeFacebookExtension extends Extension
{
    ...
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        foreach ($config['apps'] as $app)
        {
            // check for matching path here?
            foreach (array('file', 'app_id', 'secret', 'cookie', 'domain', 'logging', 'culture', 'permissions') as $attribute)
            {
                $container->setParameter('fos_facebook.' . $attribute, $app[$attribute]);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

But this is exactly where I'm stuck. Obviously, I have no access to the Request object or the DiC from within AcmeFacebookExtension to do this comparison.
Am I going completely wrong in my approach? Do you have any better idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Different questin, same goal: [Symfony2 load conditional configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603384/symfony2-load-conditional-configuration)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if setting config in your controller is the right approach though? Injecting config when the config parsing happens feels like the right way to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to create is a `CompilerPass` so that you can manipulate the `Container` after all other configuration has loaded. These should get you started:

- [Symfony2: Service Container Compiler Passes](http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2012/02/15/symfony2-service-container-compiler-passes/)
- [Symfony2: Manipulating Service Parameters and Definitions](http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/2012/02/22/symfony2-manipulating-service-parameters-and-definitions/)
- [Create a `CompilerPass`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/tags.html#create-a-compilerpass)

Comment: Top stuff, exactly what I needed. I'll take it from there. The only problem I can see is that FOSUserbundle still requires all the fos_user config to be set upon initial parsing, so right now I have to mock up some dummy config. Can you see any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried loading your bundle first? This way you could set the required parameters before the other bundles need them. (I'm not entirely sure this will work - just a guess)

Comment: Yes, I've played around with the order of bundles. The Extension->load() methods seem to get called first, and CompilerPass methods only once all extension configs are processed.
Also, since I still can't access the entire container in CompilerPass, I also can't get the Request object and have to resort to $_SERVER to get the current URL :(

Comment: Hmm... perhaps an `EventListener` (rather an a `CompilerPass`) is what you will have to implement. If all else fails, you can ignore trying to change the Symfony configuration parameters and modify the instance itself, e.g; `$container->get('fos_facebook.api')->setAppId('foo')`